# JSON parsing assitance

Tags: android, json, parsing

I can log the JSON file in my app but I'm having troubles parsing the JSON file. I'm trying to get the name of each recipe so I can display it in a RecyclerView. I do need more data from the JSON later on, would it be better to do all the parsing at once or as needed?

Here is the link to the JSON
https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/May/59121517_baking/baking.json

```
JSONObject recipeObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray recipeResults = recipeObject.getJSONArray("name");

Log.d(LOGTAG, "Recipe Results " + recipeResults.toString());
```

This is the log result

```
2018-12-13 13:56:43.622 31472-31472/com.shawn.nichol.bakingapp W/System.err:     at com.bakingapp.Data.ExtractRecipeData.recipeData(ExtractRecipeData.java:19)
```

Comment: Do it at once and store it in a object and then you get the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base object is an array of objects.

Try this:

```
JSONArray recipes = new JSONArray(jsonString); 

for(int i = 0; i < recipes.length(); i++){ 
    JSONObject recipe = recipes.getJSONObject(i); 
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "Recipe name: " + recipe.getString("name"));
}
```

Comment: This worked for me but I had to use .length() instead of .size(). any thoughts on why that would be?

Comment: he made a mistake in his code it needs to be .length because it's an array. size() works on List and ArrayList.

Answer (score 3):

first of all you need to use a tool to better understand your json structure I use jsoneditoronline see in the link the preview of your jsonobject
http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=dac21affd6544a00a553360e2c9fa311

The parsing is better done at first then you pass your data to the RecyclerViewAdapter
this library should help you a lot https://github.com/google/gson
here is a tutorial for gson : https://howtodoinjava.com/apache-commons/google-gson-tutorial-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Before trying to access name you need to access an item of the array let's say you need to get the name of the first object that is the nutella pie you do like this

```
JSONArray myJsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
JSONObject recipeObject = myJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

Log.d(LOGTAG, "Recipe Name" + recipeObject.getString("name").toString());
```

if you want to convert your JSON into java you need to

```
Recipe recipe= gson.fromJson(recipeObject.toString(), Recipe.class);
```

get all the data as so

```
List<Recipe> recipeList = new ArrayList();
Gson gson = new Gson();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
   Recipe recipe= gson.fromJson(myJsonArray .get(i).toString(), Recipe.class);
   recipeList.add(recipe);
}
```

Comment: For the record. I use and prefer gson too. If the OP was open to using other tools, I probably would have recommended it too.